# C# Weird Backslash on Convert.ToChar()

Tags: c#, unicode

I'm trying to convert a xml character entity to a C# char...

```
string charString = "&#x2081;".Replace("&#", "\\").Replace(";", "");
char c = Convert.ToChar(charString);
```

I have no idea why it is failing on the Convert.Char line. Even though the debugger shows charString as `"\\\\x2081"` it really is `"\x2081"`, which is a valid Unicode character. The exception is too many characters.

Comment: You should have only 1 character http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f3ew98y.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for `ToChar(string)` is quite readable:

> Converts the first character of a specified string to a Unicode character.

Also:

> FormatException – The length of *value* is not 1.

It will not convert a hex representation of your character into said character. It will take a one-character string and give you that character back. The same as doing `s[0]`.

What you want is:

```
string hex = "&#x2081;".Replace("&#x", "").Replace(";", "");
char c = (char)Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
```

Comment: Thank You. I didn't realise that ToChar only worked on 1 character. I should read the documentation better from now on.

Comment: The .NET docs are really quite good and almost all methods have example code as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToChar(value)` with value is a string of length 1. But `charString` is `"\\x2081"` length over 1.
Seems `"&#x2081;"` is Unicode Hex Character Code ([Unicode Hex Character Code ₁](http://www.codetable.net/hex/2081) ). So you must do that:

```
string charString = "&#x2081;".Replace("&#x", "").Replace(";", "");
char c = (char)Convert.ToInt32(charString , NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Note: It's HTML Entity (hex) of `SUBSCRIPT ONE` (see in link above ^_^)